# Write search results into new worksheet within existing search function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VERY basic VBA skill-set so I'll start by saying I'm extremely appreciative to anyone who can take the time to assist me with my question.  There are a lot of posts on this general subject, but I am looking to append an already existing code that I am using and really like.

The below code returns associated values (B:C) from a searched value (A) within a message box.  I need an additional script to take the message box search results and write them (along with the searched value) into another sheet (say we call it "TVD REPORT"). I still want to retain the below code to display the message, but also to store the search results. It seems pretty straight forward, but integrating into the existing code is way over my head.

NOTE: the Sheets("Data").Select is in there to keep the script running in the background every time the event is executed because the sheets will be protected.

```
Dim rngVis As Range
Dim VisCell As Range
Dim sFind As String

sFind = InputBox("Please enter the MD Depth to find the matching TVD depth and VS footage.")

If Len(Trim(sFind)) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("MD REPORT").Select
With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns("A"))
    .AutoFilter 1, sFind
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngVis = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    .AutoFilter
End With

'appended script to paste results into new sheet goes here??

Sheets("Data").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If rngVis Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox sFind & " could not be found."
Else
    For Each VisCell In rngVis.Cells
        MsgBox "TVD: " & VisCell.Worksheet.Cells(VisCell.Row, "B").Text & vbNewLine & _
               "VS: " & VisCell.Worksheet.Cells(VisCell.Row, "C").Text
    Next VisCell
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you wrote that and you think your skills are VERY basic, you should read some other questions on here to give you an idea of what that really is. As for your question, are the values you want to send to the other sheet VisCell.Worksheet.Cells(VisCell.Row, "B").Text and VisCell.Worksheet.Cells(VisCell.Row, "C").Text ? And does it work as of now? (Do you get the right ones)

Comment: @DavidG  Thank you! That seems to work with the exception that the associated MD (input value) isn't input with the output values. Sorry for not specifying that little part.  How would I get the input data (MD) to write into the sheet?  Also I'm curious as to why the last row would need to be defined. It seems to work for all values and any value not present is met with the appropriate message box. Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: It needed to be defined (dimmed) in his answer because he was using it but it was not dimmed (necessary if you are using option explicit - which is good practice). It also was never given any value. He edited the code right away so you could have simply not seen it when it wasn't defined at all, but it was a useless variable because it didn't contain anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Zach()

Dim rngVis As Range
Dim VisCell As Range
Dim sFind As String
Dim rpt As Worksheet
Set rpt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TVD REPORT") 'assuming this sheet is in same workbook
Dim tvd As String
Dim vs As String

sFind = InputBox("Please enter the MD Depth to find the matching TVD depth and VS footage.")

If Len(Trim(sFind)) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("MD REPORT").Select
With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns("A"))
    .AutoFilter 1, sFind
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngVis = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    .AutoFilter
End With

Sheets("Data").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If rngVis Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox sFind & " could not be found."
Else
    For Each VisCell In rngVis.Cells
        tvd = VisCell.Worksheet.Cells(VisCell.Row, "B").Text
        vs = VisCell.Worksheet.Cells(VisCell.Row, "C").Text
        MsgBox "TVD: " & tvd & vbNewLine & "VS: " & vs
        lastRow = rpt.Cells(rpt.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'dropping it in columns A and B. Change as necessary
        rpt.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1) = tvd
        rpt.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2) = vs
    Next VisCell
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @findwindow  Thank you for your assistance!  Works like a charm.

Comment: @findwindow The associated MD (input) isn't output with it's associated output values. Apologies for not specifying that little part. How would I get the input data (MD) to write into the sheet along with it's output values?

Comment: You mean sFind? Where do you want it? column c?

Comment: yessir. column a.  just so I can educate myself would it be: md= VisCell.Worksheet.Cells(VisCell.Row, "A").Text....sorry i'm attempting to hit return to separate the code but it keeps posting.... rpt.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1) = md...rpt.Cells(lastRow + 1, 2) = tvd
        rpt.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3) = vs...sorry for the mess